# Codesign wants to use the XXX keychain after XCODE revoked the certificate

Tags: xcode, certificate, keychain

Today I'seen in XCode that my certificate has expired and I had the option to click "revoke" so I did it and Xcode automatically revoked the certificate. If I open my Keychain i even see some new locked item with my name as iOS developer, but when running the project XCode is asking me for the password to unlock the keychain access but the system admin password doesn't work. Simply I don't know the password. I assume that xcode created some it's password when revoking the certificate. How to proceed?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it by removing the certificate from the keychain. (Hopefully). It didn't ask me anymore for the password when running Xcode.